# Работа библиотеки QuadFlask.colorPicker в активности вместо диалогового окна

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Нашел подходящую для меня [библиотеку](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker), но представленный код выводит диалоговое окно, как мне изменить его, чтобы всё работало просто в activity?

Comment: Там есть примеры - смотрите модуль `app`. Создать класс и разметку с таким содержанием, как в [`SampleActivity2.java`](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/flask/colorpicker/sample/SampleActivity2.java) + [`activity_sample2.xml`](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_sample2.xml)